# Opening a popup on layer option click in leafletjs

Tags: leaflet

[image]

I will be trying to show a set of options using the layerGroup functionality to filter out the markers. I need to show a popup when an option is selected from a layer which will prompt the user to enter a number based on which i will be showing the markers. Is there a possible way?

In the above sketch, there' s a sample filter at the top right which i intend to show using the layers but the thing is on selecting the 'Location' option i have to show a popup that will prompt the user to enter a location number and on that basis the markers should be placed on the map.

Answer (score -1):

I guess there would be multiple ways of achieving this, depending on what behaviour exactly you want to get.

E.g. you could use a "dummy" layer (with name "Location" probably?), that you can add in the Layers Control (I guess that is the "sample filter at the top"?). Then listen for this dummy layer for being added to the map, and launch your modal ("popup") at this time. Then when the user enters the necessary information, you can programmatically add the corresponding markers to the map.

If you need further help, please add more details on what behaviour you try to get, or start your implementation and post new questions, so that you already have a start of what you are trying to achieve and people can elaborate on it.